# Powershell Parse Text File

Tags: parsing, powershell, text

I am trying to parse this text file. It would have been easy to parse into a table like at the end, if there was a patter.

And I'm new to Powershell, so not sure how to tackle this problem.

Any help is appreciated.

```
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&361B340A&0
    Name: USB Root Hub
    Driver installed from C:\windows\INF\usbport.inf [ROOTHUB.Dev]. 2 file(s) used by driver:
        C:\windows\system32\drivers\usbhub.sys
        C:\windows\system32\drivers\usbd.sys
ACPI\PNP0C09\1
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&361B340A&1
    Name: USB Root Hub
    Driver installed from C:\windows\INF\usbport.inf [ROOTHUB.Dev]. 2 file(s) used by driver:
        C:\windows\system32\drivers\usbhub.sys
        C:\windows\system32\drivers\usbd.sys
ACPI\PNP0C09\2
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&361B340A&2
    Driver installed from C:\windows\INF\cmbatt.inf [CmBatt_Inst]. 2 file(s) used by driver:
        C:\windows\system32\DRIVERS\CmBatt.sys
        C:\windows\system32\DRIVERS\battc.sys
ACPI\PNP0C0A\2
    Name: Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery
    Driver installed from C:\windows\INF\cmbatt.inf [CmBatt_Inst]. 2 file(s) used by driver:
        C:\windows\system32\DRIVERS\CmBatt.sys
        C:\windows\system32\DRIVERS\battc.sys
```

Output

```
HardwareID      Name            File(s)
----------      ----            -------
USB\ROOT_HUB20...   USB Root Hub        C:\windows\INF\usbport.inf
USB\ROOT_HUB2...    USB Root Hub        C:\windows\system32\drivers\usbhub.sys
USB\ROOT_HUB20..    USB Root Hub        C:\windows\system32\drivers\usbd.sys
ACPI\PNP0C09\1                          C:\windows\INF\machine.inf
ACPI\PNP0C0A\1      Microsoft AC...     C:\windows\INF\cmbatt.inf
                    Microsoft AC...     C:\windows\system32\DRIVERS\CmBatt.sys
```

Comment: Your output makes no sense. How did you pair those files with those devices? Or where did "ACPI\PNP0C0A\1" come from? That's not in your reference text at all.

Comment: It's a result from devcon.exe utility. "devcon.exe driverfiles *" lists all of the information above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegEx can make fairly simple work of this. Import the file, join it together so that it's a single multiline string, then split it on lines that don't start with space. That gets you individual records. Then split those on new line characters, and parse each line depending on what's in it. Again, RegEx will help define each line is. This code will output an object for each section, with 4 properties, HardwareID, Name, Driver, and Files. The Files property is an array of files.

```psh
(Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.txt) -join "`r`n" -Split "(?m)^(?=\S)" |
    Where{$_} | 
    ForEach{
        Clear-Variable Files,Driver,Name,HardwareID
        $Files = @()
        $HardwareID = ($_ -split "`r`n")[0].trim()
        Switch -regex ($_ -split "`r`n"){
            "^\s+Name:" {$Name = ($_ -split ':',2)[-1].trim();Continue}
            "^\s+.:\\" {$Files += $_.trim();continue}
            "^\s+Driver" {$Driver = [RegEx]::Matches($_,"(?<=Driver installed from )(.+?)(?= \[)").value;continue}
        }
        [PSCustomObject]@{'HardwareID' = $HardwareID;'Name' = $Name; 'Driver' = $Driver; 'Files' = $Files}
    }
```

So that will output something like:

```psh
HardwareID                  Name                                            Driver                     Files                                                                          
----------                  ----                                            ------                     -----                                                                          
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&361B340A&0 USB Root Hub                                    C:\windows\INF\usbport.inf {C:\windows\system32\drivers\usbhub.sys, C:\windows\system32\drivers\usbd.sys} 
ACPI\PNP0C09\1                                                                                         {}                                                                             
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&361B340A&1 USB Root Hub                                    C:\windows\INF\usbport.inf {C:\windows\system32\drivers\usbhub.sys, C:\windows\system32\drivers\usbd.sys} 
ACPI\PNP0C09\2                                                                                         {}                                                                             
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&361B340A&2                                                 C:\windows\INF\cmbatt.inf  {C:\windows\system32\DRIVERS\CmBatt.sys, C:\windows\system32\DRIVERS\battc.sys}
ACPI\PNP0C0A\2              Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery C:\windows\INF\cmbatt.inf  {C:\windows\system32\DRIVERS\CmBatt.sys, C:\windows\system32\DRIVERS\battc.sys}
```

**Edit:** Ok, I'm going to assume that you didn't really try to modify what I had here since adding the Drivers to the list of other files should be really simple by changing `$Driver =` to `$Files +=` just like the line above it to add that file to the array of files as well.Although, it looks like you want a line for each file, including the driver file, so maybe having an array for the files isn't best suited for you. What you could do is output an object for the driver file, and then an object for each of the supporting files, and you could  get your version number for each on the fly as you make your objects. So you could replace the `[PSCustomObject]` line above with this:

```psh
        [PSCustomObject]@{'HardwareID' = $HardwareID;'Name' = $Name; 'Files' = $Driver; 'FileVersion' = If(Test-Path $_.Trim()){[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_.trim()).FileVersion}}
        $Files | ForEach{ [PSCustomObject]@{'HardwareID' = $HardwareID;'Name' = $Name; 'Files' = $_; 'FileVersion' = If(Test-Path $_.Trim()){[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_.trim()).FileVersion}Else{'File Not Found'}}}
```

This would output as:

```psh
HardwareID                  Name                                            Files                                  FileVersion                             
----------                  ----                                            -----                                  -----------                             
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&361B340A&0 USB Root Hub                                    C:\windows\INF\usbport.inf                                                     
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&361B340A&0 USB Root Hub                                    C:\windows\system32\drivers\usbhub.sys 6.3.9600.17238 (winblue_gdr.140723-2018)
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&361B340A&0 USB Root Hub                                    C:\windows\system32\drivers\usbd.sys   6.3.9600.17195 (winblue_gdr.140530-1506)
ACPI\PNP0C09\1                                                                                                                                             
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&361B340A&1 USB Root Hub                                    C:\windows\INF\usbport.inf                                                     
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&361B340A&1 USB Root Hub                                    C:\windows\system32\drivers\usbhub.sys 6.3.9600.17238 (winblue_gdr.140723-2018)
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&361B340A&1 USB Root Hub                                    C:\windows\system32\drivers\usbd.sys   6.3.9600.17195 (winblue_gdr.140530-1506)
ACPI\PNP0C09\2                                                                                                                                             
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&361B340A&2                                                 C:\windows\INF\cmbatt.inf                                                      
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&361B340A&2                                                 C:\windows\system32\DRIVERS\CmBatt.sys 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)
USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&361B340A&2                                                 C:\windows\system32\DRIVERS\battc.sys  6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)
ACPI\PNP0C0A\2              Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery C:\windows\INF\cmbatt.inf                                                      
ACPI\PNP0C0A\2              Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery C:\windows\system32\DRIVERS\CmBatt.sys 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)
ACPI\PNP0C0A\2              Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery C:\windows\system32\DRIVERS\battc.sys  6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. :)
How can we combine Driver File, and regular files in just one column? In other words, it lists .inf file and all other files below it.

Comment: Bascially, what I am trying to do is to find the file version of each file and put int in the next column by using this: '[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($files).FileVersion'

Comment: thats interesting.
looking at the list, driver version will be useful info to have in a column. what do you tweak in the code to get the version of the driver?

Comment: That information is not available from the file's properties, and you would probably have to search the inf file for it. Probably best suited for a new question since it's unrelated to parsing the original text file. If my answer resolves your question please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I will mark it as accepted. Thanks! The follow up question is here. [PowerShell Find Driver Version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170845/powershell-find-driver-version)